# Which mobile browsers support ES6?

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser, ecmascript-6

**[kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6)** *Only has info for iOS Safari :(*

---

I've been using *babel* for a while now, but not necessarily with Webpack but grunt instead.

Looking to create separate bundles and serve native ES6 if the browser supports it, otherwise the babel poly-filled one.

I'm having a hard time figuring out which mobile browsers, Chrome/Safari/Opera/Firefox support ES6 despite looking at their support pages?

Has anyone ever done something similar?

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ is this not good enough ?

Comment: @FabienGreard The only **mobile** browsers mentioned are iOS Safari

Comment: If you're looking for a website like the one you have mentioned in the question, then this question is **off-topic**. If you want check compatibility of specific functionalities like `import` you can check on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

ES6 support is coming along well in major desktop browsers, with Chrome at more than 90 percent compatibility, Edge at 80 percent and Safari at 54 percent. On mobile there’s just 31 percent of ES6 support for Android 5.1 users and 54 percent for iOS users.

SRC: https://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/03/09/6-reasons-need-learn-javascript-es6-now-not-later/